# Dimension-Trouble using Midpoint Rule with Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

We were asked to write the Midpoint Rule (mittelpunkt) in Matlab and apply it to solve a function in form from a vektor. We are having trouble, we think we passed some variables with wrong dimensions but cannot find the problem. We are trying to give the input as follows mittelpunkt(@(t,y)[y(2);y(1)*y(2)*t],[0,1],[3;10],50).

The code for the midpoint rule is:

```
% Input:
% f         Function handle for f(t, y)
% tspan     Interval [a, b]
% ya        Initial Value ya
% n         Number of subintervals

% Output:
% t Vector of vertices (t0, t1, . . . , tn) of size (n + 1) × 1
% y Matrix of the approximated solution values y (i) as i = 0, . . . , n of size (n + 1) × k

function [t, y] = mittelpunkt(f, tspan, ya, n) 

    % Calculate increment
    h = (tspan(2) - tspan(1)) / n;
    
    % Vectors for points in time and states
    t = zeros(n+1, 1); 
    y = zeros(n+1, numel(ya)); 
    
    % Initial values 
    t(1) = tspan(1); 
    y(1, :) = ya';
        
    % Midpoint Rule
    for i = 1:n
        t(i+1) = t(i) + h; 
        
        t_mid = t(i) + 0.5 * h; 
        
        y_mid = y(i, :) + 0.5 * h * f(t(i), y(i, :)')';
        
        y(i+1, :) = y(i, :) + h * f(t_mid, y_mid)';
    end
end
```

The other code is:

```
% Input:
% u Vector u of size (N + 1) × 1
% N Number of subintervals N

% Output:
% F Vector F(t,u) of size (N + 1) × 1

function [F] = fd_nonlin_zeit(s,u,N,t) 
  
    c = konstanten(); % Constants
    h = c.d / N;
    F = zeros(N+1, 1);

    z = (0:N)'*h;      % Create nodes

    % Left boundary condition node i=1
    F(1) = c.D * (((u(2) - (2 * h * c.SL*u(1))/c.D) - 2 * u(1) + u(2)) / h^2) - c.k * u(1) - c.k2 * u(1)^2+s(t,z(1));

    % Interior nodes from i=2 to N
    for i = 2:N
        F(i) = c.D * (u(i-1) - 2 * u(i) + u(i+1)) / h^2 - c.k * u(i) - c.k2 * u(i)^2+ s(t,z(i));
    end

    % Right boundary condition node N+1
    F(N+1) = c.D * (((u(N) - (2 * h * c.SL*u(N+1))/c.D) - 2 * u(N+1) + u(N)) / h^2) - c.k * u(N+1)- c.k2 * u(N+1)^2+ s(t,z(N+1));

    %end
```

The constants we are using are:

```
function c = konstanten()
    
    c.d = 0.3; % [µm], Thickness 
    c.D = 0.3; % [µm²/µs], carrier density  0.003 cm²/s
    c.k1 = 1; % [1/µs], recombination constant 10e6 1/s 
    c.k2 = 0.01; % [µm³/µs], recombination constant 10e-8 cm³/s
    c.Nd = 1000; % [1/µm³], doping density 10e15 1/cm³ 
    c.k = c.k1 + c.k2 * c.Nd; % [1/µs], recombination constant 
    c.SL = 0.1; % [µm/µs], Recombination rate at the respective boundary layers 10 cm/s 
    c.SR = 1000; % [1/µm], Recombination rate at the respective boundary layers 10e5 cm/s
    c.a = 10; % [1/µm], absorption constant 10e5 1/cm
end
```

I hope someone can help us find the errors in our codes. Thank you very much and if anything else is needed, let me know.